# thunderbolt 3 to pci express adapter

Tags: graphics-cards, usb, pcie, thunderbolt

I've a Thinkpad X1 3rd generation tablet, which has thunderbolt 3 slots. I am thinking about getting an external GPU enclosure since the thunderbolt 3 protocol itself supports interfacing with PCIe. What I'm looking for is a basic thunderbolt 3 to PCIe adapter. Basically just the cable with the necessary controller board.

I already have a GTX 1060 and a power supply, which is why I thought maybe I could get away cheaper if I just bought an adapter without all the extra stuff. I also don't have a set budget, but 300$ or more is a lot for just the enclosure in my opinion.

Comment: These are good questions, but we specialize more at finding something that works, rather than explaining the underlying specifics.  Try asking this question on electronics.stackexchange.com, and post a comment to the URL so we can follow it.

Comment: I was redirected here. I think the question if actual adapters exist still fits in here. I'll post the rest elsewhere

Comment: Yeah it's more complicated than you're imagining, you need a controller on the other end, along with (usually) power delivery, other I/O, etc. Some are more simplistic than others, but the suggestion of just wiring a cable to a riser won't work AFAIK. That said, if you could rewrite your question in the form of a hardware recommendation, that'd be good. Else, try superuser.

Comment: @JMY1000 right thanks for the recommendations. I changed my post accordingly

Comment: What laptop do you have? Do you already have a GPU you want to use with the enclosure? If so, what? If not, what's your total budget?

Comment: @JMY1000 it's a thinkpad x1 tablet 3rd gen.
I didn't buy it FOR gaming and I know there will be serious bottlenecks compared to having a dedicated gaming machine. But since I already have the thinkpad I thought I might as well try it with an enclosure.
I do already have a gtx 1060 and a power supply this is why I thought maybe I could get away cheaper if I just bought an adaptor without all the extra stuff.
Well I don't have a set budget but 300$ or more are a lot for just the enclosure in my opinion